# Move existing indexes from specific nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that with below config we can exclude some nodes from elastic cluster, And elastic itself relocate existing indexes on those nodes.

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
   "transient" : {
      "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "192.168.2.*"
   }
}
```

But what I really want is to exclude some indexes from particular nodes, I tried this config

```
PUT test/_settings
{
   "index.routing.allocation.exclude._ip": "192.168.2.*"
}
```

This config prohibit elastic to assign new shards to this nodes, but it seems that it does not make elastic to relocate index's shards from those node. Am I right? If I'm right how can I move existing index from particular node?

I know I can reroute shards manually but there are many shards and it is almost impossible! `_reindex` is another option but it takes even more!

If it matters I use elastic 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The answer is that that config will make elastic to move indexes from excluded nodes, But elastic do it when cluster is **green**!